# Cache publishing updates, or clients polling the cache?

Tags: microservices, caching

Context:
I am working on an application which loads a cache on startup - periodically refreshed. However it turns out that this cache is something which is very general and can be used by other applications as well. Currently as a work around other applications are using rest commands on this application to fetch data from the cache - but I think this is a wrong pattern. Alternatively, the cache should be moved into its own service which is responsible for maintaining and refreshing the cache.

My question is once the cache server is up and running - whose responsibility should it be to refresh the cache? Here are two approaches I have -

1. Services interact via messages; The caching service can publish a message to all clients, asking the clients to update their local copy of the cache as it is now stale.
2. The clients poll the caching service periodically to update their cache.

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t just use Redis?

Comment: How will using Redis solve this problem?

Comment: It does not solve the problem.  This was about why you use a homegrown solution instead of an existing one. And what you have now  is really not jusr a cache anymore

Comment: Well, technically speaking a caching server can use Redis as the cache. My question is something between - should 5 applications be loading the same cache on their own - or should be a single application which loads the cache and others can fetch data from it.

Comment: The answer here depends on your requirements; which one(s) of CAP are you prepared to give up?

Comment: Willing to drop P.

Comment: option 1 is preferable than option 2.  there can be other options , but consider these aspects - how often the cache likely to go stale, how big is the cache, how many clients?